# Sparkles and shine cocos2d shader

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, shader

I have started to work with shaders(cocos2d 2.1) and trying to make sparkles and glossy moving effect like in this game:
[game with cool shiny effects](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MR4eFeTcJUc)
There are a couple of issues with that:

1. Is there any example how to scale uv coordinates of the texture?
   Maybe in a vertex shader or somewhere before [shader use]?
2. How to scale and rotate a texture around some anchor point inside fragment shader? I understand that this is possible somehow with transformation matrixes but no luck to do that.
3. Is there any way to build sparkle programmatically to change amount
   of spikes in it?
4. As I understand glossy animated shine is a texture, maybe some white
   gradient overlaid on main texture, a kind of soft light blending in
   fragment shader. But my issue is the same as previous one. How to
   animate this gradient correctly, moving it from point a1 to point a2
   radially positioned on the main image.
5. Is it possible to make some additional function that generates
   random time to animate all this shining stuff and generate it with
   some time randomness.

Comment: Frankly, I don't see a lot of shader work in the example video that you posted. With cleverly placed animations and well drawn sprites, I think you could recreate those effects without shaders.

4. I'd achieve that effect by overlaying the skull with a sprite that has a long thin illuminated bar of light. After that, you can animate the sprite frame to move horizontally at some rate.

Comment: Can you explain with example ?